# Ubuntu 18.04 can't make it to sign in after encryption

Tags: boot, nvidia, encryption

I have an Alienware M14r2 that I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on. I thought it would be neat to install it with encryption, so I did. It worked fine until today. The only change that has happened was install a propriety NVIDIA driver. Now all I do is type my password for the encryption and I never make it to the sign in. Do I have to reinstall everything?

Edit:

The diagnostic tool gave error code 2000-0147

Solution Edit: I made my way into a recovery mode as sudo from the grub menu and apt removed nvidia-340, a driver i had wanted to test and just had a feeling might be trouble. Now everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug of the proprietary Nvidia driver (so not really an Ubuntu problem, you should probably talk to Nvidia about it...).

The problem is that somehow the driver needs acces to show the splash screen before the disk is decrypted.

The workaround to still use nvidia proprietary driver + full disk encryption is to disable the splash screen, as reported [here in the bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1721988/comments/4).

> open `/etc/default/grub`
>   and change
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
>   in the [file] to
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
>   and
>   `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Please be careful with curly quotes (`”`) next time. They will not be interpreted by GRUB.

Comment: I'll for sure try this out.

Comment: @N0rbert thanks. I was to fast with the copy-paste.